# How can I send list from view to controller (ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make export file using

```
ActionResult Download(List<UserProjectPercentReportViewModel> percentsByProjectsAndUsers)
```

method. But I can not pass a parameter. I try to send it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><input type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Download",new { percentsByProjectsAndUsers=Model})'"
                          class="btn btn-info" value="Export" /></p>
</div>
```

But I get `percentsByProjectsAndUsers.Count() == 0` in my method.

When I tried to send just string, it works, but I need to pass a `List<>`.

Comment: If you managed to pass your model to another URL by clicking the button, consider using the form post with input submit.

Comment: I suggest to use the form onsubmit(), then use ajax to properly post the data.